# Combine URL data with HTTP POST request body in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'd like to be able to POST data like this to a REST API:

```
POST /foo/b HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{ "Qux": 42, "Corge": "c" }
```

The URL segment after `foo` (i.e. `b`) also contains data that I need to capture in a server-side variable. I've tried to implement this feature in ServiceStack (see code below), but the response body is `null`.

Here's first the request type:

```
[Route("/foo/{Bar}", "POST")]
public class PostFooRequest : IReturn<PostFooResponse>
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(ParameterType = "body")]
    public Foo Body { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `Bar` is a URL variable. The `Foo` class is defined like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Qux { get; set; }
    public string Corge { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, the response looks like this:

```
public class PostFooResponse
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the service itself is defined like this:

```
public class ReproService : Service
{
    public object Post(PostFooRequest request)
    {
        return new PostFooResponse { Bar = request.Bar, Foo = request.Body };
    }
}
```

Notice that this method simply echoes the values of the `request` in the response.

When I execute the above request, I only get the `Bar` value back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"bar":"b"}
```

Setting a breakpoint in the `Post` method reveals that `request.Body` is `null`.

How do I write the code so that the API has the desired contract?

FWIW, I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40684031/126014), but the answer only explains what the problem is; not how to solve it.

Comment: The Request DTO in @Pilatus answer shows the Request DTO that matches to your HTTP Request. Note: when using a data format llike JSON the entire Request Body is always what's used to deserialize into the Request DTO, which can be further populated by /path/info and QueryStrings. Also the `[ApiMember]` are just metadata attributes that just document the API, they don't have any impact on serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would translate your current request to the following DTO the serializer should be able to fill the properties:

```
[Route("/foo/{Bar}", "POST")]
public class PostFooRequest : IReturn<PostFooResponse>
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public int Qux { get; set; }
    public string Corge { get; set; }
}
```

The serializer has no way to know how to deserialize the object you're sending.

Looking at your DTO and the request I would expect a different request.

```
POST /foo/b HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Foo": {  "Qux": 42, "Corge": "c" }
}
```

---

Other way of retrieving the `FormData` would be using the following property in your Servicestack service
`Request.FormData`. Make sure you're not calling the DTO but capital `Request`.